# Anonymous types in general

Tags: anonymous-types

This came up in another question, and I've been searching for a conclusive answer for a while now. What makes something definitively an anonymous type? Is it just simply a type created without a name, or are there more structural nuances than that?

When I say anonymous type I mean something like an anonymous class in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the term *anonymous* really just means *without name*. This is also the case with *anonymous types*.

The different nuances are probably the patterns and circumstances in which anonymous types are used, compared to named types. But other than that, I don't see any differences.